# Как в Opencart 2.3 сделать когда пользователь уже авторизован, написать не «Личный кабинет», а «Привет, {ИМЯ}!»?

Tags: opencart

Как сделать так, чтобы для авторизованного пользователя Opencart надпись "Личный кабинет" менялась на "Привет, {ИМЯ}!".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$data['text_username'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
```